# userpoints module, what's the difference between `userpoints` and `userpoints_total`?

Tags: 7, userpoints

I'm writing a SQL script to modify userpoint totals. Best I can tell the module has three tables: `userpoints`, `userpoints_total` and `userpoints_txn`. `userpoints_txn` is straightforward enough, it's a record of the individual transactions.

Both `userpoints` and `userpoints_total` seem to be aggregate of points, however, I don't understand the difference; `userpoints_total` seems redundant.

`userpoints_total` schema is:

```
uid int(11) PK
points int(11)
max_points int(11)
last_update int(11)
```

while `userpoints` has two additional columns

```
pid int(11) AI PK
uid int(11)
points int(11)
max_points int(11)
last_update int(11)
tid int(11)
```

`tid` is 0 for all rows and `pid` is auto-increment primary key. does anyone know why the module maintains both tables? both have the same number of rows and consistent values.